# Format of Discord.Role

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot, but on the part where the bot determines the Permission of the Author, it does not recognise roles, valuables like "owner" and "admin" are the ID of the role, What is the format for discord.Role?

I've tried making classes with an id and name

```
perms = 0

if moderator in message.author.roles:
 perms = 1

if admin in message.author.roles:
 perms = 2

if owner in message.author.roles:
 perms = 3

if muted in message.author.roles:
 perms = -1
```

Right now it outputs perms as 0 even though it should be 3 as my role is "owner".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the discord.py documentation `member.roles` (or `message.author.roles` in your case) returns a list of `Role` class instances, not role IDs ([documentation entry](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.AuditLogDiff.roles)).
You can read about the `Role` class in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Role) as well.

If you want to check if a member has a role with the specified ID, you can get a list of his role IDs first:

```
perms = 0
ids = [role.id for role in message.author.roles]

if moderator in ids:
 perms = 1

if admin in ids:
 perms = 2

if owner in ids:
 perms = 3

if muted in ids:
 perms = -1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now, I've been troubled with this for a while!